# Why Hasn't my Cactus Grown Deadly Spines?

Tags: botany

I recently purchased a small cactus plant from my local store for about $5.

I've been giving the cactus lots of sunlight and a good watering every week.

I've noticed that since I bought it, the other cactii at the store have sprouted long and deadly looking spikes of at least 2 inches in length. My cactus has extra little clones growing out of it but its spikes are stunted and disappointing.

Why won't my cactus grow spikes?

My cactus is of this variety:

http://www.friendsschoolplantsale.com/sites/default/files/images/colors/a-flat-cactus2-ns.jpg?1364265449

Comment: Cross posted and answered on [gardening.se]: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/13989/why-hasnt-my-cactus-grown-deadly-spines

Comment: This question has been cross-posted to "Gardening & Landscape" and answered there. The answer can be found here: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/13989/why-hasnt-my-cactus-grown-deadly-spines